# mathematical puzzle

Tags: puzzle

If you have free time you can try to solve next mathematical puzzle.

Given are four integers: `1, 3, 4, 6`
and also four basic operations: multiplication `*`, division `/`, addition `+`, substruction `-`

Every integer you can use exactly one time, but you can repeat the same operation (it means, not all operations should be used by the solution). It's strongly forbidden to use other mathematical operations (like root, potency, log, etc) or melt integers together, for example 1 (one) and 3 (three) coludn't be melted to 13 (thirteen). All mathematical rules are required (braces are alowed)! You need to get `24` as result.

Comment: I have english as a foreign language and have used the word "braces" instead "parenthesis". The rest is complete.

Comment: is given everything what you need for solution. For example if I say 24, it means of course remainder 0. And about fractions - is just another term for division :) What you need more?

Comment: this is 4 divided by 3, actually I exactly described, which operations you can only use. Sorry, your remarks are just stupid.

Comment: This is the premise of the game 24.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?$$\dfrac{6}{1-\dfrac 34}$$

Comment: yes, exactly. The division of 6 through 1/4 is the same that a product between 6 and 4

Comment: This remainds me of making 10 with 1,1,5,8.